# Get WordPress Posts By Checkbox Meta Box

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have got some posts with metadata like the following:

```
array(5) {
  ["_edit_lock"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "1494145921:1"
  }
  ["_edit_last"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  ["_thumbnail_id"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "73"
  }
  ["tpms_featured_service_checkbox"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

I am trying to find a way to find the posts that's meta value with key tpms_featured_service_checkbox equals the same as the one above.

```
$args = array(

    'post_type' => 'services',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'meta_query' => array(
      array(
          'key' => 'tpms_featured_service_checkbox',
          'value' => array(1),
          'compare' => 'IN'
      )
    ),
);
$posts = get_posts($args);
```

I tried that but doesn't work. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

The method you're using to display the meta data is misleading. Although it's being shown as an array, what you're looking for is a single value.

You have the option of setting multiple values for a single key, hence the array, however those values are stored individually in the database.

Change your meta query array to:

```
array(
    'key' => 'tpms_featured_service_checkbox',
    'value' => 1,
)
```